# enum name with multiple values

Tags: c#, enums

In my project i'm using enums example:

```
public enum NcStepType { Start = 1, Stop = 3, Normal = 2 }
```

i'm reading values from a database, but sometimes there are 0-values in my record, so i want an enum that looks like

```
public enum NcStepType { Start = 1 OR 0, Stop = 3, Normal = 2 }
```

is this possible (in c#) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a generic extension method that handles unknown values:

```
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this int value, T defaultValue)
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof (T),value))
            return (T) (object) value;
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }
```

Then you can simply call:

```
int value = ...; // value to be read

NcStepType stepType = value.ToEnum(NcStepType.Start);

// if value is defined in the enum, the corresponding enum value will be returned
// if value is not found, the default is returned (NcStepType.Start)
```

Comment: To make the function more self-explanatory i would call it ToEnumOrDefault() (like already existing linq extensions)

Answer (score 2):

No, basically. You would have to give it one of the values (presumably the 1), and interpret the other (0) manually.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not, and I'm not sure how it would work in practice.

Can't you just add logic that maps 0 to 1 when reading from the DB?

Comment: that's what i do right now, but it would be easier if i don't need to check if it's a valid value in my enum list. i'm working with a wcf service and when i'm trying to add the 0 value to my enum, it's always give me an Not Found Error

Answer (score 2):

Normally i define in such cases the 0 as follows:

```
public enum NcStepType
{
    NotDefined = 0,
    Start = 1,
    Normal = 2,
    Stop = 3,
}
```

And somewhere in code i would make an:

```
if(Step == NcStepType.NotDefined)
{
    Step = NcStepType.Start;
}
```

This makes the code readable and everyone knows what happens... (hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

No, in C# an enum can have only one value.

There's nothing that says the value in the database must map directly to your enum value however.  You could very easily assign a value of `Start` whenever you read `0` or `1` from the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum NcStepType { Start = 1 | 0, Stop = 3, Normal = 2 }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might the OP. Please share with us description as well not just code.

Answer (score 0):

No solution in C#. But you can take 2 steps:

**1. Set default value of your DB field to 1.

2. Update all existing 0 to 1.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can write this

```
enum NcStepType { Start = 0, Start = 1, Stop = 3, Normal = 2 }
```

The only problem is later there would be no way telling which `Start` was used for variable initialization (it would always look like it was the `Start = 0` one).

Comment: I would take Oliver's advice.